# Magento hidden field in newsletter subscriber

Tags: php, magento

I have an additional column GroupId in Newsletter_subscriber table. I have a hidden field in subscribe.phtml. How to write value of this hidden field in newsletter_subscriber table. I tried to make a function in observer.php but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If your hidden field has the same name as the column in the database table it should be saved automatically.

Be aware that even when you have disabled all caches magento still caches which columns are in which table, so you might have to clean your caches manually so your value will be saved.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. name is same, also cache flushed but it doesnt work. I am new to magento so can you tell me please is it because i added new field in newsletter_subscribe table directly in database not through magento  script

Comment: It makes no difference if you added the field via a magento script or directly in the database.
The saving of the subscriber is a little bit silly maybe the data is not in the model before it get's saved.
You should add an observer to the newsletter_subscriber_save_before action and check the content of `$observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber();`. If your data is missing add it in the observer. It should still be in the request you can get via `Mage::app()->getRequest()`.